# Generating SQL from UML models?

Tags: sql, database-design, uml, argouml

How do I properly generate SQL from a UML data model?

#### Attempt with ArgoUML

I have tried using "ArgoUML"; and the custom version of ArgoUML called "DB_UML".

DB_UML generates SQL files with this content, for example; from: [Books.xmi](http://modeling-languages.com/wp-content/uploads/Bookphp.xmi):

> Generate source failure. Database factory class {0} cannot be found.

ArgoUML gives me no error, and additionally doesn't produce anything. Maybe you can give me a sample working schema file?

#### Attempt with Enterprise Architect

Generated okay, but the association class was not generated anywhere.

---

Happy to use any other software on any platform which supports Oracle; as long as I can get this UML->SQL functionality working.

Comment: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/tutorials/dbdesigntools.jsp Never tried the plugin though. Comes with a free trial. Oracle JDeveloper could also be worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

GenMyModel http://www.genmymodel.com/ is now providing an online UML to SQL generator.