# How can I draw a schema for SQLite and generate its tables?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm looking for a way to draw or create a schema for SQLite and based on it, generate the tables.

I'm doing a WPF application using C# and Visual Studio 2022.

What are the most common ways to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to do it or are you looking for guidance to create a tool to do it? Because if it's the first check out [Generating SQL from UML models](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16830514/9363973), if it's the latter then it's too broad for SO.

Comment: [Where can I ask about "finding a tool, library, or favorite off-site resource?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134)

Comment: Thank you @PChemGuy , I didn't know about SoftwareRecs (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)  in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular way is probably to use [entityframework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx), You can use [code first approach](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx) to write your domain classes and generate tables from these. Be aware that there is both EF and EF core, the later for .Net core+, and the version numbers overlap.

You can also use EF with a [database first design](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx), create your tables in SQLite, and generate domain classes from this.

But you do not *need* to use an Object relational mapper. You can just create tables and SQL by hand. But this seem to be less common today.